# How can I search available PPA packages and get a list sorted by version number?

Tags: ppa

It is possible to search through the available PPAs on [this web page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas), but is there any way to perform this search and get a list of PPAs *sorted according to the version number and/or date of the most recent matching package?*

Answer (score 0):

No, the Launchpad site does not offer this feature.

However, if you enabled the PPAs on your system, you can get a list of a package `foo` ordered by version number:

```
apt-cache policy foo
```